# My SEN0188 sensor stopped work after some using

Tags: arduino, sensors, fingerprint

I bought SEN0188 sensor and I tried to use but it gives the error: "Did not find fingerprint sensor :(". After some search and datasheet checking, I found an error and updated "FINGERPRINT_VERIFYPASSWORD". After some usage and testing I finished the project, I put it in a box and after some trying, I again got "Did not find fingerprint sensor :(". I checked my code, wiring schematic, etc.. But it doesn't work.

Library: github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Fingerprint-Sensor-Library/

```
#include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>

#if (defined(__AVR__) || defined(ESP8266)) && !defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);
#else
#define mySerial Serial1
#endif

Adafruit_Fingerprint finger = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&mySerial);

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial);  // For Yun/Leo/Micro/Zero/...
    delay(100);
    Serial.println("\n\nAdafruit finger detect test");

    finger.begin(57600);
    while (true) {
        if (finger.verifyPassword()) {
            Serial.println("Found fingerprint sensor!");
            break;
        } else {
            Serial.println("Did not find fingerprint sensor :(");
            delay(1000); 
        }
    }
}

void loop() {}
```

Comment: Are you sure the sensor is correctly wired (pins 2 and 3) and powered?  Is the right path compiled in your sketch, so that `SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);` is used?

Comment: I use serial1 in arduino mega and i checked and changed about 4-5 times

Comment: In the examples provided by the Adafruit Fingerprint Sensor Library there is an [additional wait](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Fingerprint-Sensor-Library/blob/0a64b4db9b7b03c17280a9c2144f1f86099d8953/examples/fingerprint/fingerprint.ino#L46) after initializing the fingerprint serial: `finger.begin(57600);
  delay(5);`